# Create a variable with only one column of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

After doing an Sql query, I have an array that looks like the one below.

I would like to retrieve only the "name" column in a way that the names are like this:

"Name1, Name2, Name3".

I have no idea how to do this, I looked on the internet but I find nothing conclusive.

Do you have any idea how to retrieve all the data from the "name" column? Thank you in advance.

```
Array =
[1] {
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom1'
},
[2] {
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom2'
},
[3]  {
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom3'
}
```

I forgot one information: the array comes from an SQL query **rows2[].name.**

A stackoverflow member advised me to do this but it didn’t work, visual studio returns me an error message ; **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"**

```
       const result = rows2;
       const outputArray = result.map((singleResult) => singleResult.name);
       const outputString = outputArray.join(",");
       const names = rows2.map(a => a.name);

       console.log(names);
```

Comment: when you perform `console.log` of the result what did you get in the console?

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" and crash :(

Comment: Did you console and see the value of `result` ? Error message saying that `result` is undefined value

Answer (score 0):

If you have `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"` Error you can force `result` variable to be converted to an Array by doing

```
Array.from(result).map(singleResult => singleResult.name);
```